# Issue with saved GAMLSS model while predicting for new data

Tags: r, machine-learning, prediction, model-fitting, gamlss

I have a GAMLSS trained model which I have saved using `saveRDS()` in .rda format.
For eg, I trained model as:

```
gamlss_model<- gamlss(res~pb(x)+pb(y), family=BCTo, data = test)
```

When I load the above model after clearing all env variables, and use predict function for new data:

```
predict(model_old, newdata = new_data)
```

I get below error:

```
Error in eval(Call$data) : object 'test' not found
```

But this test is old dataset which shouldn't have any significance here. I am not able to understand what's wrong with this. Because of this, I cannot run REST API.

When all my env variables are there after GAMLSS model is trained, then when I use predict immediately, it works! But I want to use predictions for later.

Answer (score 0):

Try `predict(model_old, newdata = new_data, data = NULL)`

I am not sure whether that will work because I haven't worked with gamlss, but according to the documentation  `predict.gamlss` references the data that was used for fitting for whatever reason. If the NULL solution doesn't work, also loading the test data into the active session should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, I have kept that as a last option. I thought there might be some ways to avoid this. Because I want to create REST API and use it in my website. But, if there is no other way, will try loading data in active session. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I don't see a way around this using the libraries you want to use, unfortunately